# Why some Book reference requests are closed and some are not?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm just wondering some Questions (actually book request) are closed ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development ) and some questions are not closed (  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming )?

Is there any specific reason? Or just it was overlooked by the community?

**Update**

The second question is closed now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just overlooked.  They used to be acceptable back when the site first started, so there are an awful lot of them.  We just haven't had time to go through and clean them all up yet.  The one you linked to is now closed.

Comment: What about other questions like "What is a good choice of tool for...?" "What is a good choice of technology for...?" "What is a good program to help <with a particular part of programming process>?" Are those acceptable as long as they are programming related?

Comment: @zespri No, if you have a general question like that (just looking for the right tool to use) you can ask in chat, but not on the main sites. This kind of thing changes too much to keep it indefinitely.  Once you found the tool you want to use, you *can* ask any questions you need to about how to use it.