# Why some questions asking for a list of items are closed or not?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why some Book reference requests are closed and some are not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114330/why-some-book-reference-requests-are-closed-and-some-are-not)

I've [seen again and again](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbooks%5d%20closed%3a0) how some questions that ask for a suggestion of several possible options are closed, while others remain open and are highly upvoted.

Questions like:

**What book/resources/tools/etc would you recomend for the X professional?**

are most likely to remain open, and highly upvoted

While questions like:

**Books/resources/tools that every X professional would read/have**

are most likely to be closed as non constructive

It seems to me that the two questions serve the same purpose, that is, to get a
comprehensible list of highly recomended resources that the X profesional could consider for certain activity.

Comment: No, both will (and should) be closed.

Comment: Both kinds look like they should get closed. Did you happen to notice if the open ones are _old_?

Comment: Links or it didn't happen

Comment: there are [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbooks%5d%20closed%3a0) of questions, some are old, some are new

Comment: I have a long, long list of NC questions that I usually go through and close when I have the time.  But there are *thousands*.  Some examples that need to be looked through 1) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btutorial%5D+closed%3Ano 2) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbooks%5D+closed%3Ano 3) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+title%3A%22a+good%22 4) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+title%3A%22the+best%22

Comment: I guess most of those questions will be closed in the future, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @rraallvv Most of the question at that link, though tagged [books], don't actually ask for book recommendations and are perfectly fine in that regard.

Comment: @Bart Yes, precisely! my question is not about books, but tagging the search as books is the closer I could get to a list of questions like the one I'm refering to... I wonder why it is a duplicate!?

Comment: The question you ask here? Because it's answered perfectly fine by the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question with a title like

**What book/resources/tools/etc would you recomend for the X professional?**

Would likely get closed fairly quickly here because it's a shopping question, and shopping questions are considered to be off topic here.

---

You'll notice that there are a lot of highly up-voted **old** questions that would get closed rather fast today.

What Is and Is not considered on topic here changes as time goes on.

Comment: Your last sentence is a little misleading. Our outlook on which questions should be allowed on stackovflow pretty much remains consistent now. I don't think I have seen any major changes in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the top few questions in the search results you linked to, many of them have a historical lock that explains why they're still around.

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: FAQ.

I don't think there are 1,000 historical locks on SO (I could be wrong), so those will probably need to be sifted through to find the ones that still need to be closed.  (Update: Yeah, I immediately found several open posts as soon as I went deeper than 5 questions into the list.)